# Get swipe direction in Cocoa Touch

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I am trying to catch a gesture but it does not work. Here is my code:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];
```

and

```
-(void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"get gesture");
    if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
        NSLog(@"get gesture right");
    }
    if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        NSLog(@"get gesture Left");
    }
}
```

It always gets a gesture but does not recognize the direction. I also tried `if(recognizer.direction){NSLog(@"get gesture");}` and it also worked, so I do not understand where I made the mistake.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you should also NSLog recognizer.direction as well to debug what it detects.

Comment: I try but it fails and says it is not string...

Comment: incompatible type in argument 1

Comment: Try this   if (recognizer.direction == 0) {NSLog(@"get gesture right");
    }

Comment: I tried that also but it always returns 3 whetever i swipe left or right up and down

Comment: @Csabi: try NSLog(@"%@", recognizer.direction);

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You're not using the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`correctly. Its direction is always going to be what you've set it to (in this case `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft`, or 3).

If you want to capture swipes left and right that you can differentiate between, you'll have to set up a separate recognizer for each. Apple does this in their [SimpleGestureRecognizers sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleGestureRecognizers/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009460).

Answer (score 8):

What you have to do is just change the codes for adding gesture recognizer.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer;
leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
[leftRecognizer setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];
[leftRecognizer release];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer;
rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
[rightRecognizer setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];
[rightRecognizer release];
```

Answer (score 1):

UISwipe... is iOS. But for Cocoa, you can use `-swipeWithEvent:` in your view class. See the documentation at:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH13-SW10

Comment: Cocoa Touch is an iOS technology: https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/cocoa-touch.html

Answer (score 1):

Both gypsicoder and paulbailey's answers are right. For a more detailed solution of mine, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16810160/936957